# PHP extract all dates from string using Regular Expressions

Tags: php

I need help please. I would like to extract all dates from the string below.
Any help using regex or any other function? I tried using the PHP code below but I'm getting an error: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing closing parenthesis at offset 13.

```
<?php
$matches = [];
if (preg_match('/b>|-(.*?)-| (/', $dates["scheduled"], $matches) == 1) {
  var_dump($matches);
}
?>
```

Thanks.

```
<br>5449431|&nbsp;<b style='color:orange;'>SCHEDULED&nbsp;</b>|04/02/2021| ($56.49)<br>
<br>5449616|&nbsp;<b style='color:orange;'>SCHEDULED&nbsp;</b>|04/09/2021| ($51.49)<br>
<br>_______|&nbsp;<b style='color:orange;'>SCHEDULED&nbsp;</b>|04/16/2021| ($51.49)<br>
```

Comment: [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, you should show us an _attempt_ you made at least.

Comment: I know and I tried before I post this post. I added the code above, I'm asking because it seems complicated to do.

Comment: `|` and `(` are regex meta characters, thus need escaping to get matched as literals. Also what's up with "[...] getting an error". Why keep the error message a secret of sorts?

Comment: if (preg_match('/\|(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/', $dates, $matches) == 1) . The pattern works but gives only the first date. It works if I do explode the string by <br> then loop through it.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the regex meta characters `|` and `(` and remove those `-` characters, like this:

```
<?php
$matches = [];
if (preg_match('/b>\|(.*?)\| \(', $dates["scheduled"], $matches) == 1){
  var_dump($matches);
}
?>
```